# RTW Build Directory (suffix) for Subsystem

Tags: matlab, code-generation, simulink

I am trying to copy the C and H files to another directory, which are generated with the command:

```
rtwbuild('path/to/subsystem')
```

But I am having trouble determining the exact output directory used for the code generation. Until now I am using the following snippet:

```
% Assuming 'sys' is a subsystem string like from gcb
sysName = get_param(sys, 'Name');
bldInfo = RTW.GetBuildDir(bdroot(sys));
codeDir = bldInfo.CodeGenFolder;
bldSuffix = bldInfo.BuildDirSuffix;

if strcmp(mdl, sysName)
  sysName = [sysName '0'];
end
bldDir = fullfile(codeDir, [sysName bldSuffix]);
```

This seems to work for most cases, but I now have a subsystem which uses the suffix '1' (i.e. `[sysName '1']`) instead of '0'.

- How is this numeric suffix generated?
- Is there an API command which returns the correct build directory for a given subsystem? (As the above code also does not handle special characters and probably other corner cases)

*Note to overambitious downvoters: I already did search in the documentation, on Stackoverflow and Google.*

Comment: You should probably use the "pack N Go" feature, see http://uk.mathworks.com/help/rtw/examples/exporting-generated-files-using-packngo-and-buildinfo-api.html for an example